# Fixed ImageView in launch screen swiftui

Tags: ios, image, uikit, launch-screen

I'm making a launch screen for an iPad and iPhone app with some text and an image. When I run the app, the image on the iPad (portrait mode) is really big (scaled). If I run it on the iPhone it's ok.

[image]

[image]

I'm using a picture in the Assets.xcassets and call it in an Image View in the LaunchScreen.storyboard. See picture below for the constraints what I'm using.

[image: My constraints in the LaunchScreen]

Please who could give me a help on how to make a fix Image size in LaunchScreen.storyboard for every device?

Comment: you need to setup constraints in your `LaunchScreen.storyboard `

Comment: Thank for your help. That's what I tried, but still the image is scaled on an iPad. What can I do more?

Comment: Please add an image with the constraints you are using, you may be using them incorrectly

Comment: I added a picture above with the constraints what I'm using right now. Properly there's something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have static offset constraints. These conflict with your size constraints, so the result is ambiguous.

Remove them, and add center vertically+horizontally constraints instead.

Also you can remove duplicated constraints, like this:

[image]

You can also preview how your view will look on other devices directly in the interface builder. Click on `View as:` in the lower left corner and change the device.